# bootstrap enum value giving weird result

Tags: grails, enums, bootstrapping

I have a domain class that I have a controller and UI that is spitting out [object Object] for the value of an enum.

My enum is as follows:

```
enum customerenum {
  value1('value1'),
  value2('value2')
}
```

and I have a domain class customers

```
class Customer {
  customerenum ce
  String location
}
```

So now I want to bootstrap this

So in my bootstrap I have

```
class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    new Customer(
      ce:'value1',
      location:'USA'
    ).save()
  }
}
```

However in the actual page, the location shows up USA but the customerenum shows up [object Object]

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: You're code doesn't make sense.  If you've defined your variable in customer as *ce* then you would have to use that to set the value in bootstrap: *ce: customerenum.value1*.  Not sure if this is causing your issue though or if this was a copy and paste bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I need a getvalue() method in the enum as well as you need to call that method when you get the value of the enum in a class or controller.  That solved my problem